# Coffeescript unexpected token ILLEGAL, but there shouldn't be anything illegal

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This is really infuriating. I can't find anywhere in my code where I'm doing anything illegal, but for some reason, calling `fork` blows up my program. Here's the code. The relevant portion is in svgToPNG where I call `fork`.

```
{fork} = require 'child_process'
{Coral} = require 'coral'

svgToPNG = (svg, reply, log) ->
  log "converting SVG to a PNG"
  # set up a child process to call convert svg: png:-
  convert = fork '/usr/bin/env', ['convert', 'svg:', 'png:-']
  log "Spawned child process running convert, pid " + convert.pid
  # set up behavior when an error occurs
  convert.stderr.on "data", ->
    log "Error occurred while executing convert"
    reply "error"
  # set up behavior for when we successfully convert
  convert.stdout.on "data", ->
    log "Successful conversion! :)"
    log "here's the data: " + data
    reply data
  # pipe the SVG into the stdin of the process (starting it)
  convert.stdin.end svg
```

If I take the `fork` line out and replace it with something else, everything is hunky dory, but if I leave it in, I get:

```
> coffee src/coral_client.coffee
finished doing conversion to svg!
converting SVG to a PNG
Spawned child process running convert, pid 60823

/usr/bin/grep:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

It makes no sense. I don't have any weird illegal unicode character like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal), I don't believe I have any kind of parse error like in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735557/unexpected-token-illegal-somewhere)... I really don't know what's going on.

Could it be that CoffeeScript is somehow breaking the code? That seems really unlikely, but I don't know.

Comment: What file are you converting?  Shouldn't it be `convert svg:somefilename png:-`?

Comment: Have you tried to compile this script, and then run the `js` with `node`?  If the `js` looks good then the problem isn't with coffeescript.

Comment: @hpaulj the svg file is piped into the standard input of the process.

Comment: @hpaulj I get the same error when I compile to javascript and run it with `node`.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the whitespace from the `{` to the next non-whitespace character? (In `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your use of `fork`.  `fork` is for spawning Node processes, i.e. `foo.js` files.  Use `spawn` instead.

I figured this out by running a stripped down version of your code, reading an image file and then passing it to your `svgToPNG`. The error message starts:

```
/usr/bin/env:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF
```

The characters rendered in this copy/paste as `ELF` are the head characters of my binary `/usr/bin/env` file.  So `node.js` `fork` is trying to compile the `/usr/bin/env` file.  Reviewing the `child_process` documentation confirms this.  The examples running things like `ls` and `grep` use `spawn`.